# Story about homeless person’s DNA that was kept and used for clones in later times

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Pretty sure it appeared in (or at least I read it in) Fantasy and Science Fiction magazine in the late 90s or early 2000s.  Basically a homeless woman dies, her DNA is kept for later use (the person archiving the DNA even comments something like "homeless person...no one will ever want her DNA").  Anyway as I remember the story it’s basically about all the different lives that were lived by future clones of this woman.

Comment: Shades of [Henrietta Lacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Lacks) there.